# Why do I suddenly get error 530 when executing "docker pull python:3.7-slim-buster"?

Tags: python, docker, dockerhub

`docker pull python:3.7-slim-buster` was working for months fine. Now I get

```
# docker pull python:3.7-slim-buster
3.7-slim-buster: Pulling from library/python
8ec398bc0356: Already exists 
3db8034857a2: Already exists 
b05040c4362a: Pulling fs layer 
f44134f4b81c: Pulling fs layer 
e5e0271266e1: Pulling fs layer 
error pulling image configuration: received unexpected HTTP status: 530
```

I haven't seen http error 530 and I have no idea what it means.

The image was updated 3 days ago ([link](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/016bf9922e256b1f20bb9ac5b9f1263f58239fed/3.7/buster/slim/Dockerfile)) and yesterday it worked fine.

Why does that happen? Is it expected to go away or should I switch the image?

## More information

I see something similar for 9.0-cudnn7-runtime-ubuntu16.04 [in July 2018](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/jobs/83338311) - so it does not seem to be Python specific.

### Excluded issues

- Proxy: I've tried it via WLAN at work and mobile internet. It also was working the day before, so I'm pretty sure this is not the issue.
- OS / Hardware / Local Network: Another person in a different city (Frankfurt) gets the same issue

### Timeline

- ~2020-01-24 05:35 (UTC): [Push by doijanky](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7-slim-buster/images/sha256-d54d25e0eb3e47fc11edbe789105b8cad3fb42be5c7dd9f1b73f54dd609d1f61)
- ~2020-01-24 07:04 (UTC): I noticed a build fail
- 2020-01-24 08:45 (UTC): Works in Berlin... but neither in Munich nor in Frakfurt
- 2020-01-24 09:18 (UTC): `docker pull python:3.7-slim` still fails with error 530
- **2020-01-24 09:57 (UTC): Works again**

Comment: It was last pushed [42 mins ago](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.7-slim-buster/images/sha256-d54d25e0eb3e47fc11edbe789105b8cad3fb42be5c7dd9f1b73f54dd609d1f61)

Comment: Id guess it might be a small issue whilst replicating on dockerhub or just a slow push process..

Comment: Works here. Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: @Zeitounator : Other images - e.g. `python:3.8-slim-buster` - work. And it worked in the same network before

Comment: You could try downloading a free vpn like tunnelbear to find out, I'd imagine so

Comment: @MartinThoma - It sounds like a load balancing issue that should hopefully resolve itself overtime (else maybe raise an issue on their github if it persists). For the time being, you should be able to use tunnelbear to vpn yourself to berlin or somewhere that works - I'd imagine you shouldn't need to build the image too much